# Apply Color to a Specific Word

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ms-word, interop

I'm using Microsoft.Interop.Word to programmatically create a Word document. 
In a given paragraph, I need to change the font color of the word "Resolved" to green.

I've spent a lot of time searching the internet for how to do this but could not find the solution.
Here is the code I'm using to add a paragraph and text:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph pgf = document.Paragraphs.Add();
pgf.Range.InsertBefore("Issue Status is Resolved");
```

Now I want to change the color of "Resolved" to green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pgf.Range.Words[4].Font.Color = WdColor.wdColorGreen;
```

Comment: Can you expand your answer to include an explanation of your code? It helps the reader more than you might think.

Comment: Which part of the code do you think is not self explanatory? Especially in the context of the question.

Comment: Code is never self explanatory. By not including an explanation you are leaving it up to the reader to interpret what your code means. Syntax tells you _what_ you are doing, comments and explanations tell you _why_ you are doing it.

Comment: Thanks Fraytx and gunr2171. It turns out this is a little more complicated than I expressed. I was over-simplifying. I am going to close this question and start a new one with the proper detail.